# Database not working after updating the table in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, azure

I have a database table named Bookmarks and I changed the name of the primary key in the table. The primary was initially id but I changed it to BookmarkId and I can't seem to run queries after updating the PK name.I am not able to insert data into the table.

Below is the snippet of my error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Invalid column name 'Id'. Invalid
>   column name 'Id'. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack
>   trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
>   the code.  Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Invalid column name 'Id'. Invalid column name 'Id'. Source Error:
>
> Line 40:             {
>
> Line 41:                 db.Bookmarks.Add(bookmark);
>
> Line 42:                 db.SaveChanges();
>
> Line 43:                 return RedirectToAction("Index");
>
> Line 44:             }

The error occurs in Line 42, and it seems that the data cannot be inserted into the database.

This is how I defined the database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bookmarks] (
[BookmarkId] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[carparkId]  INT           NULL,
[date]       DATETIME      NULL,
[username]   NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BookmarkId] ASC),
FOREIGN KEY ([carparkId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Carparks] ([id])
);
```

The PK is set to auto incremented.

This is how I implement the code in the contro

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "carparkId,date,username")] Bookmark bookmark)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Bookmarks.Add(bookmark);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Anybody know how to resolve this error ?

Comment: Well, so tell EF that the key field is BookmarkId, not Id. Your job to configure ENtity Framework. The error is clear - it tries to use a field named "Id".

Comment: Update your entity model or code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework, then you need to update your .edmx file. Open your .edmx file, right click and update model from database (if you took the database first approach).

Answer (score 1):

> if using EDMX
>
> > then  delete your table from edmx diagram
> >
> > then  Add again your table to edmx
>
> Save, Build and done :)